# jQuery Date format invalid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Why this shows different date `05/05/1972` instead of `29/05/1970`?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert($.datepicker.formatDate('dd/mm/yy', new Date("29/05/1970")));
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/muralim/8u8xm6d8/)

Comment: FYI Your fiddle shows `NaN/NaN/NaN` for me.

Comment: Do not use the date constructor to parse strings, particularly one that isn't supposed to be supported at all. Use `new Date(1970, 4, 29)`. Parsing of strings is almost entirely implementation dependent. Most will expect the string in the OP to be m/d/y format.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, Please check this fiddle Firefox

Comment: You can try `$.datepicker.formatDate('dd/mm/yy', new Date(1970, 5-1, 29))` to show proper date. Can you please replicate bug which you mentioned, i.e. displaying 05/05/1972, since it is showing Nan/Nan/Nan as @RoryMcCrossan has mentioned

Comment: It gave me proper o/p if I use MM/DD/YYYY format in input. [see](http://jsfiddle.net/8u8xm6d8/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  alert($.datepicker.formatDate('dd/mm/yy', new Date(1970, 5, 29)));
});
```

Comment: Check the month number… months are zero based…

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `Date` object as described by W3Schools:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

```
var d = new Date();
var d = new Date(milliseconds);
var d = new Date(dateString);
var d = new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);
```

Note that month and day are 0 based, which means month is from 0-11 and date from 0-6.

Specification can be found here: 
http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.datepicker.formatDate('dd M yy', new Date('29, 05, 2014')));
```